# How do you pin each layer of a multi-layer RNN to a different GPU in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I have a multi-layer RNN composed of LSTM cells. I would like to pin each layer to a different GPU. How do you do that in TensorFlow?

```
import tensorflow as tf

n_inputs = 5
n_outputs = 100
n_layers = 5
n_steps = 20

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs])
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_outputs, state_is_tuple=True)
multi_layer_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell]*n_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of Googling I found [this code](https://github.com/nicolas-ivanov/Seq2Seq_Upgrade_TensorFlow/blob/master/rnn_enhancement/rnn_cell_enhanced.py) by Nicolas Ivanov. The trick is to create your own cell wrapper class by extending the `RNNCell` abstract class.

Here's is my take at it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class DeviceCellWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):
  def __init__(self, cell, device):
    self._cell = cell
    self._device = device

  @property
  def state_size(self):
    return self._cell.state_size

  @property
  def output_size(self):
    return self._cell.output_size

  def __call__(self, inputs, state, scope=None):
    with tf.device(self._device):
        return self._cell(inputs, state, scope)
```

Then you can use this wrapper like all the other wrappers:

```
n_inputs = 5
n_outputs = 100
devices = ["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1", "/gpu:2", "/gpu:3", "/gpu:4"]
n_steps = 20
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs])
lstm_cells = [DeviceCellWrapper(device, tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(
                                num_units=n_outputs, state_is_tuple=True))
              for device in devices]
multi_layer_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(lstm_cells, state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

We typically see two different ways to do this: either wrap around BasicLSTMCell as MiniQuark pointed out, or have a different MultiRNNCell implementation. Wrapping around BasicLSTMCell might be a better choice for your use case.